# Exclude map files from rails assets pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My Rails project contains TypeScript files which are being translated into JavaScript. For every translated `.js` file I also get a `.js.map` file. An example file structure is as follows:

```
/assets/javascripts/resources/Setting.ts
/assets/javascripts/resources/Setting.js
/assets/javascripts/resources/Setting.js.map
```

And in my `application.js` I simply do

```
//= require_tree .
```

The problem is that when this whole things gets rendered I get the following HTML (for each TypeScript file I have):

```
<script src="/assets/resources/Setting.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/resources/Setting.js.map.js"></script>
```

As you can see - for some reason Rails thinks that Settings.js.map file is to be included and automatically adds `.js` to it.

If this means anything - the TypeScript compilation happens only at IDE level, so it is not integrated into the Rails in any way.

Rails version: 4.2.1

So.. how do I exclude those map files?